# Upload to my Google Drive with php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a form with attachments on my website. Now i want these attachments to be stored in my google drive. (They should be directly uploaded to it when the user submits the form). How can i do that? - is it possible anyway?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [Zend Framework's Gdata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.introduction.html), which can be used as a standalone Version. 
With a little [Workaround](http://lamp-dev.com/using-zf-for-uploading-pdf-to-google-docs-api-3-0/289) and some help from other stackoverflow posts, i managed to build an upload function.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions I can think of.

First, if the attachment is static, I would use [save to drive button](https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive).
It is easy to integrate without backend changes

Second, [File.insert() (link for its quickstart)](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php).
You can just follow step by step php quick start tutorial to achieve your goal

Comment: "The Save to Drive button enables your web site to allow users to save files to **their** Drive account..." - that's not what i'm looking for. As i said in my question: "i want these attachments to be stored in **my** google drive"

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. But second solution would still work for your case then