# Use Google drive to obtain uploaded files instead of a PHP form

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, google-drive-api

I'm building a website for a print shop.  This shop has an 'upload file page' which is used by clients for uploading artwork, documents, etc.  Currently we use a basic php upload form that stores any uploaded file onto the server in a specific directory.

My question is: Can I replace this form with Google Drive?  I want clients to be able to upload their files/artwork to our company's Drive folder.

The reason being that less tech-savvy people who work at the print shop may be confused by using an FTP to obtain uploaded files.  Dive would be especially useful because Google has a desktop app that adds a 'hot' folder which updates as changes are made in the cloud.

Can this be done?  Or does anybody happen to know any alternative methods that would produce similar results.  Again, I'm looking to try and eliminate any FTP usage for my co-workers' sake.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload to my Google Drive with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918423/upload-to-my-google-drive-with-php)

Comment: Cant you create a (ie backend) webpage which will (read upload folder and) be used for print shop personnel to "download" data? So simple! Why u are using FTP 4 download anyway??? ps: I think using Google for professional stuff would be "very unserious" ;)

Comment: Wow Joem, I didn't even think of that... DUH!

Comment: Well yeah.. you can even create auto-email function for PHP to send e-mail to personnel after something is uploaded and thats it ;) Even DB driven for customers to enter data, so staff can be at home which file is for what! :) Anyway good luck what ever you do, but from my experience I reckon that people understand Google services for professional tasks as a very bad approach. Today, I even think that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it right away with this (on a secret link) 4 staff to get hot with new feature until you finish it as you wish..

```
<head>
//.. bla bla
</head>
<html>
<?
 $uploadfolderpath = 'your folder'; //ie 'customers/uploads'
 $files = glob($uploadfolderpath . '/*.*', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($files as $dfile)
        {
echo '<div><a href="'.$dfile.'">'.$dfile.'</div>';
}
?>
</html>
```

Good luck with print shop!

Comment: I don't really understand what that's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with Google Drive picker https://developers.google.com/picker/

It's not trivial, especially given the default behaviour of Picker is for the user to upload to his own Drive, not yours. You would need to set the user and also provide an OAuth access token that relate to your company drive account.

There is also a possibility that the user would need to be logged on to Google, which I understand would make it useless in your scenario. Worth investigating further though.